# Finding a webelement always fails while running the code but passes in debug mode

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

In the below code I am passing `url` and a `tag`.

`tag` is used to identify a div/section in a page. I am trying to get all the `url`s under a section and comparing with the passed `url` and trying to match.

Here the problem is when I run this code in the debug mode, I am able get a list of urls and find a matching `url` in the list but when I run the code below `assert` statement always fails saying `url` not found in the list. I tried my level best to fix this by introducing web elements wait and and other `sleep` methods. Nothing seems to be working. Can you please help me to fix this?

**Code**:

```
public void validateEndpoints(String url, String tag){
    tag = tag.trim();
    if(tag.contains("/"))
        tag = tag.replace("/", "_");

    WebElement resourceLink = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#resource_"+tag+"_"+" .heading a"));
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(resourceLink));
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", resourceLink);

    By mySelector = By.cssSelector("#"+tag+"__endpoint_list .path a");  
    WebDriverWait wait2 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    wait2.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(mySelector));
    List<WebElement> urlList = driver.findElements(mySelector);

    List<String> resourceName = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (WebElement e : urlList){ 
        resourceName.add(e.getText());          
    }
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", resourceLink);
    Assert.assertTrue(resourceName.contains(url), "End point "+ url +" not found in the resource " + tag + "...");      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use explicit wait on the URLs as well

```
List<WebElement> urlList = wait2.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(mySelector));
```

Comment: Tried this before posting this question but there wasn't any luck!